# Configuracion del adaptador de red

Tags: c#, variables, ip

estoy realizando un pequeño programa y necesito un poco de ayuda con esta parte:

Cargo la lista de los adaptadores de red en un ComboBox con el siguiente codigo:

```
 var myInterfaceAddress = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            .Where(n => n.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up &&
            n.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback);
            foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in myInterfaceAddress)

              CbNetwork.Items.Add(adapter.Name);

            CbNetwork.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

La idea es que al seleccionar el adaptador de red almacene en variables lo siguiente:

- IP
- Mascara de Subred
- Puerta de Enlace
- Dns
- Dns Secundario
- Mac Address

Gracias de antemano por su colaboración

Answer (score 1):

De esta manera cargo los adaptadores, y con el evento `SelectedValueChanged`, busco las propiedades del adaptador seleccionado y podes acceder mediante el foreach y revisar que propiedades y metodos te permite usar.

```
public void CargarAdaptadores()
    {
        var myInterfaceAddress = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        .Where(n => n.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up &&
        n.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback
        ).Select(x => x.Description).ToList();

        CbNetwork.DataSource = myInterfaceAddress;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cmb = sender as ComboBox;

        var collection = from p in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                         where p.Description == cmb.SelectedItem.ToString()
                         select p;
        if (collection != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                var n1 = item.GetIPProperties();
                var n2 = item.GetPhysicalAddress();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias me funciona la parte de la Mac Address, en cuanto a los demas datos los metodos y las propiedades que estan disponibles no vi una que me funcione, ademas creo que no vienen dentro del NetworkInterface.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui la funcion para La IP y Mac Adress

```
Private Function getIPAddr() As String
        'get the ip adress for check the parameter monitor on the database
        Dim myHost As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName
        Dim ipEntry As IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost)
        Dim addr As IPAddress() = ipEntry.AddressList
        Return addr(addr.Length - 1).ToString
    End Function
```

Function para la la mac addres

```
Function getMacAddress()
        Dim nics() As NetworkInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        Return nics(0).GetPhysicalAddress.ToString
    End Function
```

Espero que te sirvan.

Comment: Respondiste una pregunta de C# con lenguaje Visual Basic.