# Excepción 'System.Management.ManagementPath' cuando trato de generar Hardware ID

Tags: c#

EDIT: perdón, escribí todo en ingles por una confusión pero ya lo reescribi

Hola, quiero preguntar sobre evitar la piratería en mi software, todavía estoy aprendiendo las cosas básicas pero mi objetivo es que funcione solo en una maquina.

Según entiendo necesito obtener valores únicos para que mi software solo reconozca la maquina en el que se instalo, una manera de lograr esto es buscando una combinación de ID de hardware y para hacerlo debo acceder a "Win_32_Processor"(en principio trato de hacerlo con el processorId y luego ir agregando otras partes como motherboard)

Para esto lo hago una task que busque al processorId con WMI pero cuando compilo esto en especifico me tira una excepción.

Esta es la parte del código que me tira el error

```
Task task = Task.Run(() =>
{
ManagementObjectSearcher cpu = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
ManagementObjectCollection cpu_Collection = cpu.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject obj in cpu_Collection)
{
...
}
```

***" System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'System.Management.ManagementPath' threw an exception.' " 
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

Y el valor de "cpu" tiene un valor null, lo que me hace pensar que esta el problema ahí.

Tengo varios System.Management.dll en mi pc, trate importando algunos pero no tengo resultados distintos (version 4.7 según veo), también googlee por respuestas pero no encuentro este problema y algunas respuestas que veo no las comprendo bien (empece hace poco).

Acá hay un poco mas de información del error:

La excepción se generó originalmente en esta pila de llamadas:

```
System.Management.MTAHelper.IsNoContextMTA()
System.Management.MTAHelper.CreateInMTA(System.Type)
System.Management.ManagementPath.CreateWbemPath(string)
System.Management.ManagementPath.ManagementPath(string)
System.Management.ManagementPath.ManagementPath()
```

Yo creo que el System.Management.dll es el problema pero tampoco puedo conseguir alguno que funcione (baje un par de google)

Otra cosa es que cuando trato de abrir "wbemtest.exe" y conectarme a "root\cimv2" lo hago sin problemas, también cuando pongo en la consulta "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor" encuentro mi procesador y mi processorId sin errores y por lo que entiendo es lo que debería hacer mi programa.

(tengo windows 7 no se si sera ese el problema)

Gracias y si necesitan que ponga mas código lo haré.

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta. Es un sitio en español.

Comment: lo siento, me confundi, ahi lo traduje.

Comment: Pregunta:  Has intentado correrlo modo Administrador? click drecho al .exe> abrir como administrador... en algunos proyectos me ha pasado que funcionan diferente cuando los corres como administrador..

Comment: Hola Cristina, si ya probé en modo administrador y no me funciono. Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Todos los mac address son unicos en teoria, podrias usar ese dato para hacer lo que necesitas. Te dejo un link de una respuesta mia. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/351677/configuracion-del-adaptador-de-red/351714#351714

Comment: Perdon por la demora en la respuesta, vere el link que me enviaste con atencion!